# BERT fine tuning

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I'm trying to create my model for question answering based on BERT und can't understand what is the meaning of fine tuning. Do I understand it right, that it is like adaption for specific domain? And if I want to use it with Wikipedia corpora, I just need to integrate unchanged pre-trained model in my network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine tuning is adopting (refining) the pre-trained BERT model to two things:

1. Domain
2. Task (e.g. classification, entity extraction, etc.).

You can use pre-trained models as-is at first and if the performance is sufficient, fine tuning for your use case may not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Finetuning is more like adopting the pre-trained model to the downstream task. However, recent [state-of-the-art](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.04925.pdf) proves that finetuning doesn't help much with QA tasks. See also the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218778/fine-tuning-distilbertforsequenceclassification-is-not-learning-why-is-loss-no/63593996#63593996).