# Fine-Tuning DistilBertForSequenceClassification: Is not learning, why is loss not changing? Weights not updated?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, text-classification, loss-function, huggingface-transformers

I am relatively new to PyTorch and Huggingface-transformers and experimented with DistillBertForSequenceClassification on this [Kaggle-Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/nlp-getting-started).

```
from transformers import DistilBertForSequenceClassification
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn as nn
from transformers import get_linear_schedule_with_warmup

n_epochs = 5 # or whatever
batch_size = 32 # or whatever

bert_distil = DistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
#bert_distil.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(in_features=768, out_features=1), nn.Sigmoid())
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(bert_distil.parameters(), lr=0.1)

X_train = []
Y_train = []

for row in train_df.iterrows():
    seq = tokenizer.encode(preprocess_text(row[1]['text']),  add_special_tokens=True, pad_to_max_length=True)
    X_train.append(torch.tensor(seq).unsqueeze(0))
    Y_train.append(torch.tensor([row[1]['target']]).unsqueeze(0))
X_train = torch.cat(X_train)
Y_train = torch.cat(Y_train)

running_loss = 0.0
bert_distil.cuda()
bert_distil.train(True)
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    permutation = torch.randperm(len(X_train))
    j = 0
    for i in range(0,len(X_train), batch_size):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        indices = permutation[i:i+batch_size]
        batch_x, batch_y = X_train[indices], Y_train[indices]
        batch_x.cuda()
        batch_y.cuda()
        outputs = bert_distil.forward(batch_x.cuda())
        loss = criterion(outputs[0],batch_y.squeeze().cuda())
        loss.requires_grad = True
   
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
   
        running_loss += loss.item()  
        j+=1
        if j == 20:   
            #print(outputs[0])
            print('[%d, %5d] running loss: %.3f loss: %.3f ' %
              (epoch + 1, i*1, running_loss / 20, loss.item()))
            running_loss = 0.0
            j = 0
```

> [1,   608] running loss: 0.689 loss: 0.687
> [1,  1248] running loss: 0.693 loss: 0.694
> [1,  1888] running loss: 0.693 loss: 0.683
> [1,  2528] running loss: 0.689 loss: 0.701
> [1,  3168] running loss: 0.690 loss: 0.684
> [1,  3808] running loss: 0.689 loss: 0.688
> [1,  4448] running loss: 0.689 loss: 0.692  etc...

Regardless on what I tried, loss did never decrease, or even increase, nor did the prediction get better. It seems to me that I forgot something so that weights are actually not updated. Someone has an idea?
O

**what I tried**

- Different loss functions

  - BCE
  - CrossEntropy
  - even MSE-loss
- One-Hot Encoding vs A single neuron output
- Different learning rates, and optimizers
- I even changed all the targets to only one single label, but even then, the network did'nt converge.

Comment: You learning rate is to high. Try a smaller one like 1e-4 or 1e-5.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I just played with the learning rate to see if anything changes... but even if there is only one class in the dataset, it doesn't seem to learn anything...

Comment: Try to overfit on a single batch. Also not relevant to your question, but: you don't need to call model.forward() explicitly - just do model(X); and no need for doing loss.requires_grad = True.

Comment: Even overfitting on a single batch does not change anything, the loss stays around 0.65 but changes the same as before... very strange

Answer (score 3):

Looking at running loss and minibatch loss is easily misleading. You should look at epoch loss, because the inputs are the same for every loss.

Besides, there are some problems in your code, fixing all of them and the behavior is as expected: the loss slowly decreases after each epoch, and it can also overfit to a small minibatch. Please look at the code, changes include: using `model(x)` instead of `model.forward(x)`, `cuda()` only called once, smaller learning rate, etc.

Tuning and fine-tuning ML models are difficult work.

```
n_epochs = 5
batch_size = 1

bert_distil = DistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(bert_distil.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

X_train = []
Y_train = []
for row in train_df.iterrows():
    seq = tokenizer.encode(row[1]['text'],  add_special_tokens=True, pad_to_max_length=True)[:100]
    X_train.append(torch.tensor(seq).unsqueeze(0))
    Y_train.append(torch.tensor([row[1]['target']]))
X_train = torch.cat(X_train)
Y_train = torch.cat(Y_train)

running_loss = 0.0
bert_distil.cuda()
bert_distil.train(True)
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    permutation = torch.randperm(len(X_train))
    for i in range(0,len(X_train), batch_size):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        indices = permutation[i:i+batch_size]
        batch_x, batch_y = X_train[indices].cuda(), Y_train[indices].cuda()
        outputs = bert_distil(batch_x)
        loss = criterion(outputs[0], batch_y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
   
        running_loss += loss.item()  

    print('[%d] epoch loss: %.3f' %
      (epoch + 1, running_loss / len(X_train) * batch_size))
    running_loss = 0.0
```

Output:

```
[1] epoch loss: 0.695
[2] epoch loss: 0.690
[3] epoch loss: 0.687
[4] epoch loss: 0.685
[5] epoch loss: 0.684
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This interrupts with an error: RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn. Any idea where this needs to be fixed?

Comment: I have no idea where to fix if I don't look at your code. Did you copy the above code exactly? The error suggests that autograd is turned off for some tensors.

Answer (score 2):

I would highlight two possible reasons for your "stable" results:

1. I agree that the **learning rate** is surely too **high** that prevents model from any significant updates.
2. But what is important to know is that based on the state-of-the-art papers **finetuning has very marginal effect** on the core NLP abilities of Transformers. For example, the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.04925.pdf) says that finetuning only applies really small weight changes. Citing it: "Finetuning barely affects accuracy on NEL, COREF and REL indicating that those tasks are already sufficiently covered by pre-training". Several papers suggest that  finetuning for classification tasks is basically waste of time. Thus, considering that DistilBert is actually a student model of BERT, maybe you won't get better results. ***Try pre-training*** with your data first. Generally, pre-training has a more significant impact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As mentioned above, I tried different learning rates, so this is not the problem here. I haven't tried pretraining, but I guess there is more of a practical problem: Even with only one single label in the dataset, the model does not converge...

Answer (score 0):

I have got similar problem when I tried to use `xxxForSequenceClassification` to fine-tune my down-stream task.

At last, I changed `xxxForSequenceClassification` to `xxxModel` and added `Dropout` - `FC` - `Softmax`. Magically it's solved, loss decreased as expected.

I'm still trying to find out why.

Hope it may help you.

FYI, transformers verion: 3.5.0

Comment: Probably you forgot to set model to train mode, see the line `bert_distil.train(True)` in my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the poor performance is due to gradients being applied to the BERT backbone. Validate it like so:

```
print([p.requires_grad for p in bert_distil.distilbert.parameters()])
```

As an alternative solution, try freezing the weights of your trained model:

```
for param in bert_distil.distilbert.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

As you are trying to optimize the weights of a trained model during fine-tuning on your data, you face issues described, among other sources, in the ULMIfit (https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.06146) paper